# sum values by different group in one table

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I got Table 1 and Table 2 based on a same dataset, but different groupings.

For Table 1, it groups on Group 1 and Group 2, For Table 2, it groups on Group 1 only. 
I want something like the result table -  to combine the results from Table 1 and Table 2.

The logic is =iif( Field name is C, sum values based on Group 2, sum values based on Group 1). 
It should be easy, but I can not figure out how to achieve that. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You can use the same gruping settings used in table 1, check if the column is C then sum(Fields!Data.Value,"Group2") otherwise sum(Fields!Data.Value,"Group1"). For further help share a dataset sample.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Thank you.  I have tried sum(Fields!Data.Value,"Group1") and sum(Fields!Data.Value,"Group2"), but it returns to a total sum of all the 3 IDs' values, i.e. a same sum number for each ID row. How can I correct it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression to determine the scoping group.

Create a tablix and set the `group 1` like below (in my case `Group3` in Column Groups). Then right click the group and go to `Group properties`.

[image]

In the `General` tab add an expression for `Group on` property and put this expression:

```
=IIF(
Fields!Group.Value="C",
Fields!SubGroup.Value,
Fields!Group.Value
)
```

Use the same expression in the header cell of the column group (the cell selected in the above image).

It will preview the following tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.